# Proving $\exists C>0$ s.t. $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)\leq C$ for geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: inequality, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I am trying to show that $\exists$ a constant $C>0$ s.t. $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)\leq C$ for geometric BM $\mathrm{d}X_t=r\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\mathrm{d}W_t$ for $r>0$. I thought this would have appeared on this site before but I can’t find any trace of it here. I am not sure what theorems I should be using. So far, here's what I think could be (potentially) useful for proving this.

1. $X_t>0$ a.s. It. is also a submartingale.
2. Writing $t\wedge T$ and using $T$ as a (fixed and deterministic) stopping time, and possibly using Fatou's lemma since $X_t$ is non-negative.
3. Doob's submartingale inequality (although it seems to operates on $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{t\in[0,T]}X_t^2)$ instead).
4. $f(x)=x^2$ is convex (although Jensen’s inequality goes in the opposite direction of the requested inequality).

I'm not particularly where to begin. Generally speaking, I have trouble proving inequalities when it comes to stochastic processes, does anyone have a good framework to tackle such problems?

Comment: I would expect that applying Ito formula to $X_{t}^{2}$ is a good start and eventually try to apply Gronwalls lemma.

Comment: Are $r$ and $\sigma$ constants?

Comment: @UBM yes they are, although it would be interesting to see how they extend to adapted processes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote 'geometric Brownian motion', I am going to assume that there is a typo and the SDE is
$$dX_t = X_t r dt + X_t \sigma dW_t,  \quad X_0 = x_0 \in \mathbb R \quad \text{ on } [0,T]. \tag{1}$$

where $r$ and $\sigma$ are constants.

The solution to the SDE (1) is $X_t = x_0 e^{(r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t} e^{\sigma W_t}.$ Then
\begin{align}
E[X_t^2] &= x_0^2 e^{2(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t} E[e^{2 \sigma W_t}] \\
&= x_0^2 e^{2(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t} e^{2 \sigma^2 t},
\end{align}
where in the last equality I have used the fact that $2\sigma W_t \sim N(0,4\sigma^2t)$ and for a normal random variable $Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we have $E[e^Y]=e^{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}.$

Thus, we have two cases. If $(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) \geq 0,$ then
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} E[X_t^2] = x_0^2 e^{2(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)T} 
e^{2 \sigma^2 T},$$
otherwise
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} E[X_t^2] = x_0^2 e^{2 \sigma^2 T}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Will edit the typo later. Generally, how do you know where to begin to prove a particular inequality? I spent ages look at Doob’s inequality, requirements for $L_2$-boundedness etc. and got nowhere. Doing what you did would have hardly crossed my mind!

Comment: In this case we know the solution of GBM, that's why I went for this approach. But if the SDE was more general, for example $dX_t = f(X_t,t)dt + g(X_t,t)dW_t,$ then we would have to use some of the inequalities you mentioned and the exercise would be very different.

Comment: if I extended made $r$ and $\sigma$ adapted processes, not necessarily deterministic, how would one go about determining the conditions for this inequality to hold?

Comment: It would be a very different proof. There is a proof in Mao's book.  I can write a proof if you want but it may be better in a new question since the proof is very different.

Comment: which chapter/page is that on? I’ll give it a look!

Comment: page 51, Lemma 3.2.